# how to know if the image is 32-Bit ,24-Bit ,8-Bit , 1-Bit in each pixel

Tags: java, image, image-processing, pixel

I am posting this question after a lot of Google searching
I want to convert an image to array of bits , but my research guide to know that for each image the pixel in it could be 32 bit or 24 bit ... etc 
So how to know the number of bits for the pixel in each image ?

Comment: I think it is not possible to tell by just looking at bits. You probably should look at header http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143022/determine-bits-per-pixel-in-a-bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

You need use javax.ImageIO API

```
ColorModel color = ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpg")).getColorModel();
color.getPixelSize();
```

Comment: Relevant javadocs: [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html), [`ColorModel.getPixelSize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html#getPixelSize%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [`java.awt.image.RenderedImage`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/image/RenderedImage.html), you can call `getData` to get the [rasterised data](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html) for that image.

This is essentially a pixel-by-pixel plot of the data, and indeed you can call `getPixel(int x, int y, double[] dArray)` to get an array of the data for a single given pixel.